# OpenCV Java Mat Pixels Alteration

Tags: java, opencv, pixel

What I want to do is to retrieve specific pixels from Mat object, alter it and eventually replace it. Most examples are for C++, so some of the functions doesn't exist in Java.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

get Mat from bitmap:

```
org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, originalMat);
```

clone otherMat for processing:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(orginalMat, otherMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
```

get / set hsv values of each pixel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++) {
     double data[] = otherMat.get[j, i];
     // get
     hValue = data[0];
     sValue = data[1];
     vValue = data[2];
     //set
     data[0] = xx;
     data[1] = xx;
     data[2] = xx;
     otherMat.put(j, i);
   }
}
```